# How do you set timeout in the middle of several promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, timeout, promise

I'm using node/express and I need to set a very long timeout measured in days in the midst of a number of promises.

My code is like:

```
.then(function(thing){
setTimeout(function(thing), 5000)
.then(function() {
//do something else
```

Everything runs perfectly well before and after including the function in the middle of setTimeout but the timeout is completely ignored.. For the purposes of iteration, I made the timeout 5 seconds instead of days for any wise guys out there.

Comment: Are you using any Promise library? It might have a helper function

Comment: I wasn't but I do have Q/q installed . . . it's the only place I need it and I don't really know how to use Q, nor do I know if it has a helper function; is there an easier way?

Comment: If you are not using Q, how are you creating the promise then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using Parse, I guess you can make a custom promise like...

```
function pWaiter(time){
    var promise = new Parse.Promise();
    setTimeout(function(){
        promise.resolve();
    }, time);
    return promise;
}
```

and use it like:

```
...
.then(function(thing){
    return pWaiter(5000);
}).then(function() {
...
```

Comment: Thank you. I lost faith in Parse a long time ago but I just tried it and it actually worked!

Comment: initally, I was worried that what I was doing might be anti-pattern, but according to [Promise-anti-patterns](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns), the above code is acceptable.

Comment: Yes, creating a Promise is not an anti-pattern when used to "promisify" something. Here, you are promisifying a timeout, so that's OK.